# extract last 12 character and copy it to txt

Tags: batch-file

my input file named done.txt as per below.

clip_id HCQLR01HM01AO

clip_id HAUGL01HM01AC

clip_id HEBQC01HM01CD

clip_id HEFCD01HM01AK

clip_id HBYVA01HM01CY

clip_id HCFJI01HM01AI

And i want to extract last 12 char and write into new text file with name res.txt

this is my coding. but this only works for 1st line. How to loop it for 2nd,3rd and 4th lines?

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\com\done.txt) do (

    set line=%%a
    set chars=!line:~-13,12!
    echo !chars! > res.txt
)
pause
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The single ">" in `echo !chars! > res.txt` overwrites res.txt each time. Change this line to `echo !chars! >> res.txt`

You might also want to remove res.txt before the loop, resulting in:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

del res.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\com\done.txt) do (

    set line=%%a
    set chars=!line:~-13,12!
    echo !chars! >> res.txt
)
pause
```

Comment: @Poobalan If you would like to keep the res file from the previous run and just append to it, remove the line `del res.txt`